# python program to parse the json file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing python program the json input into the proper dictionary format but I am unable to complete the parsing logic. This is my python program.

```
import json
list1 = []
dict1 = {}
 
data_file = "inp2.json"
file = open(data_file)
for line in file:
    json_line = json.loads(line)
    dict1["id"]=json_line["id"]
    json_line = json_line["List1"]
    for i in range(len(json_line)):
        i_val = i + 1
        dict1["sub" + "_n" + str(i_val)]=json_line[i]['sub']
        dict1["subReport_a" + "_n" + str(i_val)] = json_line[i]['subReport']['a']
        dict1["subReport_b" + "_n" + str(i_val)] = json_line[i]['subReport']['b']
        #print("out:", dict1)
        for j in range(len(json_line[i]['otherList'])):
            ancl = json_line[i]['otherList'][j]
            n_val = j + 1
            dict1["otherList_id" + "_n" + str(n_val)] = ancl['id']
            dict1["otherList_a" + "_n" + str(n_val)] = ancl['other_rep']['a']
            dict1["otherList_b" + "_n" + str(n_val)] = ancl['other_rep']['b']
 
    print("dict:", dict1)
```

inp2.json has the following data:

```
{"id":101,"List1":[{"sub":"P1","subReport":{"a":74,"b":65},"otherList":[{"id":5,"other_rep":{"a":67,"b":65}},{"id":6,"other_rep":{"a":66,"b":65}}],"x":322},
{"sub":"P2","subReport":{"a":86,"b":65},"otherList":[{"id":7,"other_rep":{"a":65,"b":65}},{"id":2,"other_rep":{"a":64,"b":65}}],"x":59}]}
{"id":102,"List1":[{"sub":"P3","subReport":{"a":74,"b":65},"otherList":[{"id":8,"other_rep":{"a":67,"b":65}},{"id":9,"other_rep":{"a":63,"b":65}}],"x":1068}]}
```

My expected output of 1st line is(id – 101):

```
dict: {'id': 101, 'sub_n1': 'P1', 'subReport_a_n1': 74, 'subReport_b_n1': 65, 'otherList_id_n1': 5, 'otherList_a_n1': 67, 'otherList_b_n1': 65, 'otherList_id_n2': 6, 'otherList_a_n2': 66, 'otherList_b_n2': 65, 'x':322,'sub_n2': 'P2', 'subReport_a_n2': 86, 'subReport_b_n2': 65, 'otherList_id_n1': 7, 'otherList_a_n1': 65, 'otherList_b_n1': 65, 'otherList_id_n2': 2, 'otherList_a_n2': 64, 'otherList_b_n2': 65, 'x':59}
```

but I am getting the below output.  I am not sure where I am missing the parse logic. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.
dict: {'id': 101, 'sub_n1': 'P1', 'subReport_a_n1': 74, 'subReport_b_n1': 65, 'otherList_id_n1': 7, 'otherList_a_n1': 65, 'otherList_b_n1': 65, 'otherList_id_n2': 2, 'otherList_a_n2': 64, 'otherList_b_n2': 65, 'sub_n2': 'P2', 'subReport_a_n2': 86, 'subReport_b_n2': 65}

Comment: What is incorrect in output that you have?

Comment: So, for the first line, you're missing the `"x": 322`?

Comment: It is able to parse only till "{"sub":"P2","subReport":{"a":86,"b":65}"   from the input